# SolrConfig inclusion through Xinclude

Tags: solr, xerces, xinclude, riak-search

I'm currently using a Solr implementation inside of Riak KV server. In respect of Riak defaults and not to fear any software ugrade I need to include extra configuration into my core SolrConfig.xml. I'll be doing this programmatically through Ansible command. I want to add as few line as possible in the factory settings solrconfig.xml.

I need to include a bunch of `<searchComponent>` and `<requestHandler>` inside my config, for that I was wishing to use this kind of pattern:

```xml
    <config>
      <!-- snip -->
      <xi:include href="solrconfig_extra.xml" xpointer="xpointer(//searchComponent)" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" />
      <xi:include href="solrconfig_extra.xml" xpointer="xpointer(//requestHandler)" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" />
    </config>
```

with a configuration file looking like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<container>
  <searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
   <lst name="spellchecker">
     <str name="name">suggest</str>
     <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
     <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookupFactory</str>
     <str name="field">myterms</str>  <!-- the indexed field to derive suggestions from -->
     <float name="threshold">0</float>
     <str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
  <!--
     <str name="sourceLocation">american-english</str>
  -->
   </lst>
  </searchComponent>

  <requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/suggest">
   <lst name="defaults">
     <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
     <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest</str>
     <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
     <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
     <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
   </lst>
   <arr name="components">
     <str>suggest</str>
   </arr>
  </requestHandler>
</container>
```

Unfortunately, Xerces don't support the `xpointer()` schema, and as the `element()` only accept element index, and would require as much insert as the include container has children.

How can I achieve this inclusion in an orderly manner ?

- Is it easy to switch from xerces to another xmlparser ? I must remind you that I don't want to alter vendor solution as much as possible.
- In SolrConfig grammar there is maybe a neutral element that would allow me to be included in configuration (for instance /config/NEUTRALMAGICTAG/requestHandler to be interpreted as /config/requestHandler )
- Should I renounce and forget about XInclude and work my way through pure ansible file edition ?

Answer (score 1):

TYPO3 uses [XML includes for the Solr configuration](https://github.com/TYPO3-Solr/ext-solr/blob/master/Resources/Solr/typo3cores/conf/russian/schema.xml#L29). This might be helpful.

Beware though that the latest Solr uses dynamic schemas, which may rewrite the files with all the various includes into a unified **managed-schema** file (e.g. for schemaless mode). You can disable it or never trigger the rewrite, just need to be deliberate about it.